# How do I split a df column with multiple delimiters into different columns?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a column in my dataframe with multiple delimiters: 'QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE', 'FLEX', 'DST' and my goal is to split these values by their delimiter into different columns.

One of the problems I run into is that str.split() only takes one pattern as well as there being multiple 'RB', and 'WR' in each column so it would only split the first one.

In each row there is:
1 'QB'
2 'RB'
3 'WR'
1 'TE'
1 'FLEX'
1 'DST'

I've looked into regex expressions, but from what I've read I worry that a range of letters won't be good enough since these delimiters are particularly exact.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `re` should do your job

```py
In [36]: new_string = "QB fwef QBw wewe RD wewewedcewRDfwe"

In [37]: import re

In [38]: re.split('QB|RD',new_string)
Out[38]: ['', ' fwef ', 'w wewe ', ' wewewedcew', 'fwe']
```

And then since you get a list, you can fit those elements accordingly into individual columns.

Comment: This only works if columns are the same every time. Given this looks potentially like football teams, and not all teams have the same number of players for each position, this might not be the case.

Comment: Okay gotcha, you hadn't mentioned that in the question

Comment: It is not my question, I'm only guessing

Comment: I've updated the picture to the question. The number of positions on these teams are static with updated listings above. I'll see what I can do with the above solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. I come up with the following solution:

```
>>> 'fds afs DF fdfasfasf ew ER fjoijo'.replace('DF','XXX').replace('ER','XXX').split('XXX')
['fds afs ', ' fdfasfasf ew ', ' fjoijo']
```

To apply it to all rows in one coulmn use `map` method on
Series. Wrap it into lambda function and pass to `map` as argument.